# how to record all oracle select statement executed on table oracle

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to record all oracle select statement executed on specific table oracle
and  `pc ip address`, `windows username`, `PC name`

in other words I need to know who and when a table was read..

I searched and found the this query will return `pc ip address`, `windows username`, `PC name`

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'),
       SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'HOST'),
       SYS_CONTEXT ('userenv', 'OS_USER')
  FROM DUAL;
```

But I am wondering does this will return correct information when there is no database on that pc ?

since trigger cannot be launched on select then How to deal with that case ?

I am using oracle forms 6i application if there is possible solution too

Answer (score 3):

You can use database auditing for individual SQL DML/DDL statements.

Example:

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba
SQL> alter system set audit_trail=DB,EXTENDED scope=spfile;
```

Reboot the database.

I have a table called `T1` and I want audit `SELECT` statements fired against it.

```
SQL> audit select on t1 by access;

Audit succeeded.

SQL> select * from t1;

no rows selected
```

The audit information can be obtained from `USER_AUDIT_TRAIL` view.

```
SQL> select OS_USERNAME,USERNAME, USERHOST, SQL_TEXT, ACTION_NAME from dba_audit_trail where obj_name='T1';

OS_USERNAME     USERNAME    USERHOST        SQL_TEXT            ACTION_NAME
------------    ---------   ------------    -----------------   ------------
oracle           JAY        myserver.js     select * from t1    SELECT
```

[Individually Auditing SQL Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28337/tdpsg_auditing.htm#TDPSG50523)

Comment: that's will work with oracle9i but it wont show me the sql_text is their any work around?

Comment: You can project `ACTION_NAME` column as my update suggests, which only tells which DML/DDL was used not the complete statement.

Comment: @atokpas What is the purpose of `by access` here?

Comment: @atokpas Is rebooting the database necessarty for the changes to take place?